# Altcoin nodes connection issues

Tags: blockchain, altcoin, nodes

I have cloned litecoin for fun and i am struggling with connecting to nodes. I have generated genesis block and compilation all works fine.

I have two litecoin daemons running on my local Macosx and on amazon vps but i cant seem to connect both.  I am running mainnet on port 26201

i tried running ./litecoind -daemon -addnode=x.y.y.y but it is not working.

chainparams.cpp

```
class CMainParams : public CChainParams {
public:
    CMainParams() {
        strNetworkID = "main";
        consensus.nSubsidyHalvingInterval = 100000;
        consensus.BIP34Height = 710000;
        consensus.BIP34Hash = uint256S("e6024058338254100b68f794f3a5d14f9b9a7f0bfb68bf302d63c47c027b64ca");
        consensus.BIP65Height = 918684; // bab3041e8977e0dc3eeff63fe707b92bde1dd449d8efafb248c27c8264cc311a
        consensus.BIP66Height = 811879; // 7aceee012833fa8952f8835d8b1b3ae233cd6ab08fdb27a771d2bd7bdc491894
        consensus.powLimit = uint256S("e6024058338254100b68f794f3a5d14f9b9a7f0bfb68bf302d63c47c027b64ca"); 
        consensus.nPowTargetTimespan = 3.5 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 3.5 days
        consensus.nPowTargetSpacing = 2.5 * 60;
        consensus.fPowAllowMinDifficultyBlocks = false;
        consensus.fPowNoRetargeting = false;
        consensus.nRuleChangeActivationThreshold = 6048; // 75% of 8064
        consensus.nMinerConfirmationWindow = 8064; // nPowTargetTimespan / nPowTargetSpacing * 4
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].bit = 28;
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].nStartTime = 1199145601; // January 1, 2008
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_TESTDUMMY].nTimeout = 1230767999; // December 31, 2008

        // Deployment of BIP68, BIP112, and BIP113.
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].bit = 0;
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].nStartTime = 1485561600; // January 28, 2017
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_CSV].nTimeout = 1517356801; // January 31st, 2018

        // Deployment of SegWit (BIP141, BIP143, and BIP147)
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].bit = 1;
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].nStartTime = 1485561600; // January 28, 2017
        consensus.vDeployments[Consensus::DEPLOYMENT_SEGWIT].nTimeout = 1517356801; // January 31st, 2018

        // The best chain should have at least this much work.
        consensus.nMinimumChainWork = uint256S("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400040");

        // By default assume that the signatures in ancestors of this block are valid.
        consensus.defaultAssumeValid = uint256S("0x3095c904a9907471390b80730bb760b28754501006cd7fe8ea0943dd71796c51"); //1353397

        /**
         * The message start string is designed to be unlikely to occur in normal data.
         * The characters are rarely used upper ASCII, not valid as UTF-8, and produce
         * a large 32-bit integer with any alignment.
         */
        pchMessageStart[0] = 0xfb;
        pchMessageStart[1] = 0xc0;
        pchMessageStart[2] = 0xb6;
        pchMessageStart[3] = 0xdb;
        nDefaultPort = 26201;
        nPruneAfterHeight = 100000;

        genesis = CreateGenesisBlock(1518803474, 4251767 , 0x1e0ffff0, 1, 1000 * COIN);
        consensus.hashGenesisBlock = genesis.GetHash();



        //printf("Genesis hash:  %s\n", consensus.hashGenesisBlock.ToString().c_str());
        //printf("Merkel root:  %s\n", genesis.hashMerkleRoot.ToString().c_str());


        assert(consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0xe6024058338254100b68f794f3a5d14f9b9a7f0bfb68bf302d63c47c027b64ca"));
        assert(genesis.hashMerkleRoot == uint256S("0x29b1458191d86739ff3ef0f179c0927a95cb89fa054e3e2a41dfe843ee0acc42"));

        // Note that of those with the service bits flag, most only support a subset of possible options
        //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.citizenshipcoin.org", true);
        //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.thrasher.io", true);
        //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.litecointools.com", true);
        //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.litecoinpool.org", true);
        //vSeeds.emplace_back("dnsseed.koin-project.com", false);

        base58Prefixes[PUBKEY_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,11);
        base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,5);
        base58Prefixes[SCRIPT_ADDRESS2] = std::vector<unsigned char>(1,50);
        base58Prefixes[SECRET_KEY] =     std::vector<unsigned char>(1,176);
        base58Prefixes[EXT_PUBLIC_KEY] = {0x04, 0x88, 0xB2, 0x1E};
        base58Prefixes[EXT_SECRET_KEY] = {0x04, 0x88, 0xAD, 0xE4};

        vFixedSeeds = std::vector<SeedSpec6>(pnSeed6_main, pnSeed6_main + ARRAYLEN(pnSeed6_main));

        fDefaultConsistencyChecks = false;
        fRequireStandard = true;
        fMineBlocksOnDemand = false;

        checkpointData = (CCheckpointData) {
            {
                { 1, uint256S("0xcbf5d62bd22c4bbd616bd59b2b634d2fa896a4192a5c24298b26e1d9454e8559")},
                { 3, uint256S("0x3095c904a9907471390b80730bb760b28754501006cd7fe8ea0943dd71796c51")},
                { 5, uint256S("0x11f32abdff3d58c27ebbf53ff1fbc15aabef8b5f7665fd84ba3ce1f368402798")},
           /*     { 23420, uint256S("0xd80fdf9ca81afd0bd2b2a90ac3a9fe547da58f2530ec874e978fce0b5101b507")},
                { 50000, uint256S("0x69dc37eb029b68f075a5012dcc0419c127672adb4f3a32882b2b3e71d07a20a6")},
                { 80000, uint256S("0x4fcb7c02f676a300503f49c764a89955a8f920b46a8cbecb4867182ecdb2e90a")},
                {120000, uint256S("0xbd9d26924f05f6daa7f0155f32828ec89e8e29cee9e7121b026a7a3552ac6131")},
                {161500, uint256S("0xdbe89880474f4bb4f75c227c77ba1cdc024991123b28b8418dbbf7798471ff43")},
                {179620, uint256S("0x2ad9c65c990ac00426d18e446e0fd7be2ffa69e9a7dcb28358a50b2b78b9f709")},
                {240000, uint256S("0x7140d1c4b4c2157ca217ee7636f24c9c73db39c4590c4e6eab2e3ea1555088aa")},
                {383640, uint256S("0x2b6809f094a9215bafc65eb3f110a35127a34be94b7d0590a096c3f126c6f364")},
                {409004, uint256S("0x487518d663d9f1fa08611d9395ad74d982b667fbdc0e77e9cf39b4f1355908a3")},
                {456000, uint256S("0xbf34f71cc6366cd487930d06be22f897e34ca6a40501ac7d401be32456372004")},
                {638902, uint256S("0x15238656e8ec63d28de29a8c75fcf3a5819afc953dcd9cc45cecc53baec74f38")},
                {721000, uint256S("0x198a7b4de1df9478e2463bd99d75b714eab235a2e63e741641dc8a759a9840e5")}, */
            }
        };

        chainTxData = ChainTxData{
            // Data as of block 59c9b9d3fec105bdc716d84caa7579503d5b05b73618d0bf2d5fa639f780a011 (height 1353397).
            1516406833, // * UNIX timestamp of last known number of transactions
            19831879,  // * total number of transactions between genesis and that timestamp
                    //   (the tx=... number in the SetBestChain debug.log lines)
            0.06     // * estimated number of transactions per second after that timestamp
        };
```

chainparamsseeds.h

```
#ifndef BITCOIN_CHAINPARAMSSEEDS_H
#define BITCOIN_CHAINPARAMSSEEDS_H
/**
 * List of fixed seed nodes for the litecoin network
 * AUTOGENERATED by contrib/seeds/generate-seeds.py
 *
 * Each line contains a 16-byte IPv6 address and a port.
 * IPv4 as well as onion addresses are wrapped inside a IPv6 address accordingly.
 */
static SeedSpec6 pnSeed6_main[] = {
   // {{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x0d,0x3b,0xbd,0x0b}, 26201}
};

static SeedSpec6 pnSeed6_test[] = {
    //{{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x0d,0x3b,0xbd,0x0b}, 26202}
};
#endif // BITCOIN_CHAINPARAMSSEEDS_H
```

litecoin.conf (macosx)

```
rpcuser=litecoinrpc
rpcpassword=xxxx
addnode=xx.xx.xx.xx:26201
```

i dont have litecoin.conf on my vps node.

debug.log (macosx)

```
2018-02-23 17:07:18 0 addresses found from DNS seeds
2018-02-23 17:07:18 dnsseed thread exit
2018-02-23 17:08:19 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2018-02-23 17:08:19 Adding fixed seed nodes as DNS doesn't seem to be available.
2018-02-23 17:09:19 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2018-02-23 17:10:20 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2018-02-23 17:11:20 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2018-02-23 17:13:22 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
2018-02-23 17:15:23 socket recv error Connection reset by peer (54)
```

debug.log (vps)
The debug.log on my vps shows this (lots of lines) with port numbers cycled.

```
2018-02-23 17:09:19 connection from x.x.x.x:55668 dropped (banned)
2018-02-23 17:09:19 connected to self at y.y.y.y:49226, disconnecting
```

I know x.x.x.x is my ip of macosx and y.y.y.y is local vps server public ip address.

Why is it iam not able to connect to nodes?

Looking at the debug.log why are the IP's cycling through different ports over 55,000 instead of connecting to 26201 where it is supposed to connect?

Comment: It started to work, after i deleted the .~/.litecoin` folder except wallet.dat on both nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> 2018-02-23 17:09:19 connection from x.x.x.x:55668 dropped (banned)
> ```

Looking at what you have posted in your question, your node is dropped because it is banned.

You need to clear your ban list for starters and possibly work out why it was banned - from the logs.

> Looking at the debug.log why are the IP's cycling through different ports over 55,000 instead of connecting to 26201 where it is supposed to connect?

The ports over 55,000 are the *from* ports, since you are seeing the connection attempt in your logs the *to* port is 26201 presuming you have                                                                                                                                                                                                                    everything correctly configured as described.